# VBNet Expected Expression when calling function returning string matrix

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function that (should) return a 2d string array/matrix from random records in a DB

```
Function GetRndRecords(table As String, fields As String(), num_records As Integer) As String(,)
    If not connected Then
        Connect()
    End If
    Dim Rand as New Random()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ID_Max As Integer
    Dim Results(num_records,fields.Length) As String
    strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & table
    dbcomm = New OleDbCommand(strSQL,dbconn)
    ID_Max = dbcomm.ExecuteScalar()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i=0 To num_records-1
        Do
            Dim Rand_ID As Integer = Rand.Next(1,ID_Max)
            Dim j As Integer
            strSQL = "SELECT "                                      ' strSQL begin
            For j = 0 To fields.Length-1
                If(j <> 0) Then
                    strSQL &= ", "
                End If
                strSQL &= fields(j)
            Next
            strSQL &= " FROM " & table & " WHERE ID = " & Rand_ID   ' strSQL end
            dbcomm = New OleDbCommand(strSQL,dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            dbread.Read()
            For j = 0 To fields.Length-1
                Results(i,j) = dbread.GetString(j)
            Next
        Loop Until dbread.GetString(0) <> ""
    Next
    Return Results
End Function
```

I don't get any problem IN this function, but i get one ("BC30201: Expression expected.") when i call it (in Page_Load event)

```
Sub Page_Load
    Dim Rand_Records As String(,)
    Rand_Records = GetRndRecords("Autore",{"ID","Nome"},PossibleAnswers-1)
End Sub
```

I even tried this, with the same result

```
Sub Page_Load
    Dim Rand_Records As String(,)
    Rand_Records = new String({"ID1","Nome1"},{"ID2","Nome2"},{"ID3","Nome3"})
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Right code `Dim Rand_Records As String(,) = {{"ID1", "Nome1"}, {"ID2", "Nome2"}, {"ID3", "Nome3"}}`

Comment: yep, i arrived at the same resolution few seconds ago, but still the function doesn't work :(

Comment: Dim Rand_Records As String(,)
  Dim s() As String = {"ID", "Nome"}
  Rand_Records = GetRndRecords("Autore", s, PossibleAnswers - 1)

Comment: omg, really? Now it works (thanks :D), but i'm surprised it didn't before, if the problem is the "staticism" of an array

Comment: BTW, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171802/passing-a-constant-array-to-a-function-in-vb-net. In other words, You should rewrite call `Rand_Records = GetRndRecords("Autore", New String() {"ID", "Nome"}, PossibleAnswers - 1)`