# Calling of subs is not working and keeps saying "Argument not specified for parameters"

Tags: arrays, vb.net, parameters

I tried to use value from Sub `PromptUser` in `Sub Main` but I cannot. It says:

> Argument not specified for parameter SaS
>   EmailAddress, StudentName, SaS is not declared and may be inaccessible due to protection level

`StudentName`, `EmailAddress` and `SaS` are Arrays:

```
Module Module1
Private StudentName(2) As String
Private EmailAddress(2) As String
Private SaS(2) As String
    Public Sub PromptUser(ByVal StudentName() As String, ByVal EmailAddress() As String, ByVal SaS() As String)

        For i = 0 to 2
            Console.WriteLine("enter your name: ")
            StudentName(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("enter your e-mail")
            EmailAddress(i) = Console.ReadLine
            SaS(i) = StudentName(i) & "#" & EmailAddress(i)
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        Dim SSN1 As String
        PromptUser(StudentName(), EmailAddress(), SaS())
        For i = 0 to 2
            Console.WriteLine("enter name to search: ")
            SSN1 = Console.ReadLine()
            If SSN1 = StudentName(i) Then
                Console.WriteLine(SaS(i))
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You're not passing the `SaS()` parameter to the `PromptUser` sub. You're calling it:  `PromptUser(StudentName(), EmailAddress())` with just 2 arguments; the sub expects 3. You also ned to initialize the arrays somewhere. You're not showing where.

Comment: @Jimi so you're telling that i should edit it and make it PromptUser(StudentName(), EmailAddress(), SaS())??? if so then it didn't work and i just need name and email for the 2nd part not SaS pls correct me wherei went wrong

Comment: Show where those arrays are initialized.

Comment: i haven't found any syntax to call arrays in subs can u help me by clarifying what u mean by showing where arrays are initialized? @Jimi

Comment: Where have you declared those arrays? Something like: `Private StudentName(2) As String` etc.. You're passing them as arguments, but nowhere you're showing when/where they have been declared/initialized. Do you know what these last two terms mean?

Comment: Public Sub PromptUser(ByVal StudentName() As String, ByVal EmailAddress() As String, ByVal SaS() As String) isnt this the declartion? i found it on web. @Jimi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171802/passing-a-constant-array-to-a-function-in-vb-net this is the link @Jimi

Comment: No. That is the declaration of a Sub (a Method). When you call that sub, the arrays must already exist. They also need to be declared in the Module scope (fields). Those string arrays are non-exitent until you have declared them. Since those are arrays, you also need to initialize them. Add `Private StudentName(2) As String` `Private EmailAddress(2) As String` `Private SaS(2) As String` right after `Module Module1`. Also, change the loops in `For i = 0 To 2 (...)`: .Net collections are `0` based.

Comment: You can see in the question you linked that the array that's being passed to the sub is declared (`Dim`) and initialized in-place: `Dim MyArray As String() = {"some", "array", "members"}`.

Comment: @Jimi i did do as u corrected but when i enter name it shows error saying object reference not set to instance of an object and when i hover pointer to Private StudentName(2) Private EmailAddress(2) Private SaS(2) it says make field read only.    and i also changed it in Sub Main putting  PromptUser(StudentName(2), EmailAddress(2), SaS(2)) to call

Comment: **`Private StudentName(2) As String`** etc. and `PromptUser(StudentName, EmailAddress, SaS)`. If you have changed your code, post the new code, updating your question. Click on the `edit` link just below the question's content.

Comment: @Jimi thanks alot really appreciate it.It worked but what i didnt get it was why private? i mean wasant private supposed to limit the variable use to Sub PromptUser only i thought public would do the job pls help me clarify it

Comment: It's `Private` in the Module scope. Visible to all code in `Module1`. Not visible outside of it.

Comment: Thanks alot @Jimi for your time and effort to help me clarify my errors out really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Remember to change the loops: **`For i = 0 To 2`**, otherwise you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: You are trying to pass uninitialized fixed-length arrays by value.  Pretty sure that at least one or more of those things need to be changed.